# NAudio WaveIn.DataAvailable Event: Separating Channels

Tags: naudio

Assume a Stereo `WaveIn` whose samples are being intercepted through the `WaveIn.DataAvailable (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WaveInEventArgs)` event. How could the samples *of a specific channel* (i.e. Right/Left) be extracted from `e.Buffer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samples are stored interleaved. So if you are recording 16 bit samples, the first two bytes are a left channel sample, the second two bytes are a right channel sample, then another left sample, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Reply 3 years later in case someone else is trying to read left and right channel from `WaveIn`. I adapted the [Microphone Demo](https://github.com/swharden/FftSharp.git), specifically the [FormMicrophone.cs](https://github.com/swharden/FftSharp/blob/master/src/FftSharp.Demo/FormMicrophone.cs) to the following:

```
 private void cbDevices_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wvin?.Dispose();
        wvin = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent();
        wvin.DeviceNumber = cbDevices.SelectedIndex;
        
        //Changed this line to have 2 instead of 1 channel
        wvin.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(rate: SAMPLE_RATE, bits: 16, channels: 2);
        wvin.DataAvailable += OnDataAvailable;
        wvin.BufferMilliseconds = 20;
        wvin.StartRecording();
    }

    double[] lastBuffer;
    double[] lastBufferRight;
    private void OnDataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs args)
    {
        int bytesPerSample = wvin.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8;
        int samplesRecorded = args.BytesRecorded / bytesPerSample;
        if (lastBuffer is null || lastBuffer.Length != samplesRecorded)
        {
            lastBuffer = new double[samplesRecorded/2];
            lastBufferRight = new double[samplesRecorded/2];
        }

        int indexBuffer = 0;
        for (int indexSample = 0; indexSample < samplesRecorded; indexSample+=2)
        {
            lastBuffer[indexBuffer] = BitConverter.ToInt16(args.Buffer, indexSample * bytesPerSample);             
            lastBufferRight[indexBuffer] = BitConverter.ToInt16(args.Buffer, (indexSample+1) * bytesPerSample);
            ++indexBuffer;
        }
    }
```

If you want to try it out this [tone generator](https://www.szynalski.com/tone-generator/) was perfect to check single sin waves on left and right channel